# Mysql left join table2 where field from table3

Tags: mysql

table media

```
id, options
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

table maps

```
id, title, type
1   f      x
2   g      x    
3   h      y    
4   z      x
4   w      y
```

table media maps

```
maps_id  media_id   
1        2
2        3
```

I am trying to select all data from table media and join table maps. Each media can contain multiple maps.

```
SELECT media_t.id, media_t.options,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN maps_t.type = 'x' THEN maps_t.title END ORDER BY maps_t.title SEPARATOR ', ') as x,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN maps_t.type = 'y' THEN maps_t.title END ORDER BY maps_t.title SEPARATOR ', ') as y
    FROM media_table as media_t
    LEFT JOIN maps_table as maps_t
    ON media_t.id = (
        SELECT maps_id FROM {table_media_maps} 
        WHERE media_id = maps_t.id
    )
    GROUP BY media_t.id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need  a 3 tbals join you could try

```
SELECT me.id, me.options,
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN ma.type = 'x' THEN ma.title END ORDER BY ma.title SEPARATOR ', ') as x,
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN ma.type = 'y' THEN ma.title END ORDER BY ma.title SEPARATOR ', ') as y
FROM media as me
LEFT JOIN media_maps mm on me-id = mm.media_id 
LEFT JOIN maps  ma  ON mm.maps_id = ma.id
GROUP BY me.id
```

Answer (score 0):

your data is not coplete, for all case.
I put a right join  for the maps table, so that you cansee that it works, problably you want there also a left join, but you still need to join all three tables

> ```
> CREATE TABLE media_table  (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `options` VARCHAR(1)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO media_table 
>   (`id`, `options`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'a'),
>   ('2', 'b'),
>   ('3', 'c');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table_media_maps (
>   `maps_id` INTEGER,
>   `media_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table_media_maps
>   (`maps_id`, `media_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2'),
>   ('2', '3');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE maps_table  (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `title` VARCHAR(1),
>   `type` VARCHAR(1)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO maps_table 
>   (`id`, `title`, `type`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'f', 'x'),
>   ('2', 'g', 'x'),
>   ('3', 'h', 'y'),
>   ('4', 'z', 'x'),
>   ('4', 'w', 'y');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT media_t.id, media_t.options,
>     GROUP_CONCAT(
>     CASE WHEN maps_t.type = 'x' THEN maps_t.title END
>     ORDER BY maps_t.title SEPARATOR ', ') 
>     as x,
>     GROUP_CONCAT(
>     CASE WHEN maps_t.type = 'y' THEN maps_t.title END
>     ORDER BY maps_t.title SEPARATOR ', ') 
>     as y
>     FROM media_table as media_t
>     LEFT JOIN table_media_maps m_m_t ON media_t.id = m_m_t.media_id
>     right JOIN maps_table as maps_t
>     ON maps_t.id = m_m_t.maps_id
>     GROUP BY media_t.id, media_t.options
> ```
>
> ```
>   id | options | x  | y   
> ---: | :------ | :- | :---
> null | null    | z  | h, w
>    2 | b       | f  | null
>    3 | c       | g  | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e041e85996d51fddbaaaff72da916b8e)*

Comment: what is the difference between yours and scaisEdge solution?

Comment: his solution will not show the first row, because right join get all data and try to join it with the rest. , elsw it is the same solution as you can see

Comment: Just to observe that RIGHT JOINs are vanishingly rare

Comment: yes, but i don't mind, as i test my query i notoced that the data was incomplete, and showed no GROUP_CONACT at all, so i build it in, just to see, but i mentioned that he wanted probably a LEFT JOIN anyway